# Algorithm for "erase as few numbers as possible to make remaining in increasing order"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I’m reading "Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach" and met this question in Chapter 1:

> Problem 1.3: You have a list of numbers, erase as few numbers as possible to make remaining numbers in increasing order.

For example, given the array

```
9 44 32 12 7 42 34 92
```

Two possible options are `9 12 42 92` and `32 42 92`, and the former has fewer numbers removed.

I tried a recursive algorithm but not satisfied with its performance, because it still need to test too many combinations. I found a heuristic algorithm that can get good result fast, though I'm not sure if it can guarantee the best result. I searched online but didn't find any discussion on this question. I believe there should be a better algorithm.

I wrote my 2 methods [here](http://dracodoc.wordpress.com/2014/08/16/solution-to-erase-as-few-numbers-as-possible-to-make-remaining-in-increasing-order-in-r/) in case you want to check.

UPDATE: I was asking solutions to this question, @josilber and @templatetypedef gave the links and the right direction to look at. It turned out that this is a special case of a family of known problems with good solutions. There is no need to write detailed solution here, the wiki page of Longest increasing subsequence, Patience sorting provided detailed information.

It's worth noting that although the answers have some links, this question is not about asking for resources or links. The real answer is the knowledge of "this question is a variation of some known solved problems".

Comment: This problem is NP-Hard, right?  And a breadth first search should give a correct answer.  Just checking what other folks think before I do any more research.

Comment: Check out the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence), which includes pseudocode.

Comment: @markspace There's an O(n log n) solution, so it's probably not NP-hard.

Comment: Is there a (specific) programming question in here?

Comment: This is a specific algorithm question. I probably should remove the java tag though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an unsolved problem.

Comment: What do you mean "unsolved"? It is a question because I'm looking for better solution. It's answered because the answer and comments gave links to known solution which solved the problem. The question itself is a variation of known solved problem, but I didn't know this when I asked the question, and it's impossible to search and find the answer.

Comment: It's interesting that some of you would classify this question as "asking to recommend or find resource". The question is asking for an answer, but it happened to be a variation of known solved questions so there is no need for detailed explanation of the solution, some links are enough. The key point is the knowledge of the right direction, which is impossible to know or to search before somebody else tell you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a hint, this is equivalent to finding the longest increasing subsequence of the array (do you see why?) Since that's a standard algorithm with known O(n log n) solutions, you should be able to solve the problem with a slight modification of LIS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right direction! There seemed to be known O(n log log n) algorithm for the special case of 1:n permutation (which is this question).